# has ::std::has_nothrow_default_constructor been moved/changed?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, std

In trying to [build boost mirror](http://kifri.fri.uniza.sk/~chochlik/mirror-lib/html/#download) with gcc 4.7.2, I ran into this error, but oddly enough, I see [this documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00501.html).

*Has `::std::has_nothrow_default_constructor` been moved/changed?*

```
In file included from /home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits.hpp:20:0,
                 from /home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/mirror_base.hpp:38,
                 from /home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/mirror.hpp:16,
                 from /home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/src/mirror/example/all_member_variables.cpp:10:
/home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits/is_default_constructible.hpp:31:2: error: ‘has_nothrow_default_constructor’ is not a member of ‘std’
/home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits/is_default_constructible.hpp:28:9: error: parse error in template argument list
/home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits/is_default_constructible.hpp:31:43: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘::’ token
/home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits/is_default_constructible.hpp:31:51: error: expected initializer before ‘||’ token
In file included from /home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits.hpp:21:0,
                 from /home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/mirror_base.hpp:38,
                 from /home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/mirror.hpp:16,
                 from /home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/src/mirror/example/all_member_variables.cpp:10:
/home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits/is_copy_constructible.hpp:31:2: error: ‘has_nothrow_copy_constructor’ is not a member of ‘std’
/home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits/is_copy_constructible.hpp:28:9: error: parse error in template argument list
/home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits/is_copy_constructible.hpp:31:40: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘::’ token
/home/kfeng/src/mirror-lib/include/mirror/type_traits/is_copy_constructible.hpp:31:48: error: expected initializer before ‘||’ token
make[2]: *** [src/mirror/example/CMakeFiles/mirror-all_member_variables.dir/all_member_variables.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/mirror/example/CMakeFiles/mirror-all_member_variables.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**ANSWER using Pubby's Note Below**

Something like this should work with gcc 4.7.2 - I will submit a patch and let the maintainer decide how best to deal with it.

```
template <typename T>
 struct is_default_constructible
  : std::integral_constant<
        bool,
        ::std::has_trivial_default_constructor<T>::value ||
#if __cplusplus>=201103L 
        ::std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>::value ||
#else
        ::std::has_nothrow_default_constructor<T>::value ||
#endif
        mirror::_class::_<T>::has_default_ctr::value>
 { };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11 it was changed to `std::is_nothrow_default_constructible` to be more consistent with naming.

Comment: +1 tyvm - I will edit the code and try it out - quick aside, there must be an `#ifdef` I can use to check if `--std=c++11` has been passed in... ...gonna google for it

Comment: @kfmfe04 You could just use `boost::has_nothrow_default_constructor`

Comment: @kfmfe04 Also, `__cplusplus` is the macro you can check, although it might not guarantee that the trait is there.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at documentation for GCC 4.6.2, but using GCC 4.7.2, so it's not very surprising  they don't match.

The traits were renamed by [n3142](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3142.html)

See a previous answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/12716778/981959 for some code that attempts to detect which is supported by your compiler, although a comment says it doesn't work with libc++.